# Issue with jetty, log4j and parentloaderPriority

Tags: java, log4j, jetty

I am using jetty 6.

I am using a library which requires me to set parentloaderPriority to true. However this messes up my log4j and for some reason I cannot log to my log file anymore (the file appender doesn't work). I don't know if this a known and documented issue? All I googled seems to imply that it's better with parentloaderPriority to true! whereas I have the exact opposite, if I set it back to false, my log4j file gets logged in again. Anything I should be checking in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebAppContext.parentLoaderPriority` property is for embedded Jetty users only.

All it does is flip the classloader priority from:

**Servlet API Mandated Behavior**

```java
WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(false)
```

When a WebApp attempts to resolve a class or resource, the webapp's own ClassLoader is used first, then the parent classloader (which in the case of Jetty is the server classloader)

to

**Java Default Behavior**

```java
WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true)
```

When a class or resource is resolved, use the parent classloader first, then the child classloader.

Comment: "The WebAppContext.parentLoaderPriority property is for embedded Jetty users only." I am using it in a non embedded context and it does make a difference, is this normal? I know what the setting does, my question was more about the issue with log4j libraries and if there was anything I could do, ie remove the log jars from my war file if it is a conflict problem, etc.. any idea? Thanks for your answer BTW ;-)

Comment: Don't flip it in non-embedded use.  You will break things, especially in Jetty 6 (that much is evident with your question).  In Jetty 9+ we have the ability to support server and webapp isolate logging, or even force the webapp to use the server logging.  See http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-logging.html  - the problems you are experiencing are just compounded with Jetty 6 as its far **TOO OLD** to handle it easily (short of rewriting the WebAppClassloader layer in Jetty 6 yourself)

Comment: Oh I see. I will move everything to jetty 9 then. Thanks!